# Jinja2 with Ansible, multiple variables in loop

Tags: for-loop, ansible, jinja2

I am using Jinja2 Template with Ansible in order to generate a HaProxy configuration.
I have some issues when I want to add multiple variables in the same loop.

var file:

```
haproxy_url:
  - site1
  - site2

servers:
  - 'server1 192.168.11.2'
  - 'server2 192.168.11.3'
```

Template file:

```
### Backends

{% for url in haproxy_url %}

backend {{ url }}
    errorfile 503 /etc/haproxy/503.http
    mode http
    option http-keep-alive
    cookie SRVNAME insert
    option httpchk GET / HTTP/1.1\r\nHost:\ {{ url }}
{% endfor %}
    http-check expect string Something
    default-server inter 3s fall 3 rise 2
{% for server in servers %}
    server {{ server }}:80 cookie SA check
{% endfor %}
```

Result right now:

```
### Backends

backend site1
    errorfile 503 /etc/haproxy/503.http
    mode http
    option http-keep-alive
    cookie SRVNAME insert
    option httpchk GET / HTTP/1.1\r\nHost:\ something

backend site2
    errorfile 503 /etc/haproxy/503.http
    mode http
    option http-keep-alive
    cookie SRVNAME insert
    option httpchk GET / HTTP/1.1\r\nHost:\ something
    server server1 192.168.11.2:80 cookie SA check
    server server2 192.168.11.3:80 cookie SA check
```

Unfortunately, I am doing something wrong and I don't have the servers in the first block.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the part

```
{% for server in servers %}
    server {{ server }}:80 cookie SA check
{% endfor %}
```

has to be included inside

```
{% for url in haproxy_url %}
...
{% endfor %}
```

to work, so move the first `{% endfor %}` to the bottom.